# Securing bundles on request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I am having an asp.NET MVC application in which there are many bundles defined. Right now the bundles are served as it is without checking whether user session exists or not using bundle URL. I want to secure few of these static resources such as bundles or CSS or any other JS so that they are only served when user session is there even if with a direct URL access.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: You can achive this using IPrincipal object.

Ex:

if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
//Load bundle
}

Answer (score 0):

I had added below code to my web.config and it started working

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add  name="FormsAuthenticationModule"  
 type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove  name="UrlAuthorization" />
  <add  name="UrlAuthorization" 
type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"  />
  <remove  name="DefaultAuthentication" />
  <add  name="DefaultAuthentication"  
type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

Now one can use the standard ASP.NET permissions in web.config to force forms authentication for all files in the directory.

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```